# Android phone not recognized by PC but works fine with Mac

Tags: usb, android

Rather a weird issue I am having here. Recently something happened to my Nexus 5 Android phone and it stopped being recognized by the PC saying that the device has malfunctioned. Please see the error message below:

[image]

The funny thing that it works fine on Mac laptop.

I have tried:

- Different USB ports
- Different PCs
- Different USB cables
- Tried both Windows 7 and Windows 10

This is behaviuor persists on all of them.

Given the fact that the device is still in working order (as it works well on Mac), I suspect that it might be some weird setting or configuration that I am missing? I tried different USB connection modes though (MTP/Camera). I also tried to enable/disable the debug mode.

Any ideas?

Comment: So it fails on any PC with any USB port and any USB cable, but works on Mac?  Suppose you go to a shop and they plug it into their PC with their cable, does it fail for them?

Comment: @barlop What shop do you mean?

Comment: I just mean if joe shmoe tried it in their non-mac computer would it fail as well. It just seems so strange if it fails in multiple PCs but works on  a MAC. Have you tried it on multiple Macs?

Comment: I don't know if usb debugging mode would make a difference.. try turning that off, if it's on.  If  you  haven't heard of it then you probably never turned it on. 'cos it may even be a hidden setting quite tricky to turn on.

Comment: @barlop well I assume I've got that option covered by trying at least 5 absolutely different PC/cable configurations including at work.

Comment: @barlop Yes, I tried switching the debug option on and off as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51222/discussion-between-barlop-and-eugene-s).

Answer (score 0):

**1st try**: Have you tried re-installing the USB drivers? This could solve the problem for you (I had a similiar problem with my Nexus 5).

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html

---

**2nd try**: Is MTP enabled on the phone?

Settings > Storage > Menu > USB connection to the computer

Also in the Developer Options there is a default behaviour "Select USB Configuration" you could set it to MTP too.

---

**3rd try**: Wipe the **cache** partition, this solved most of my strange problems during development.

https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-32767

Comment: Yep, tried that.

Comment: Is MTP enabled?

It should be under
Settings > Storage > Menu > USB connection to the computer
(sorry have Cyanogen on mine now)

Comment: Also in the Developer Options there is a default behaviour "Select USB Configuration" you could set it to MTP too.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I tried MTP as well.

Comment: I also found this very voodoo-ish article:
http://windowsreport.com/windows-10-doesnt-recognize-android/

Solution 8> Turn on Airplane mode (can't hurt to try it)

Comment: I would also add: Wipe the **cache** partition, this solved most of my strange problems during development. https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-32767

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that I tried on both: Windows 7 and Windows 10. I will try wiping the cache.

Answer (score -1):

Check in Device Manager if the device is shown properly.

If not (shown in Other devices) maybe you have to install OEM USB Drivers

Check here for more:
[Install OEM USB Drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html)